# Fetch particular column value from rows with specified condition using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, for-loop, openstack

I have a sample output from a command

```
+--------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+ 
| id                                   | fixed_ip_address | floating_ip_address | port_id                             |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
| 04584e8a-c210-430b-8028-79dbf741797c |                  | 99.99.99.91        |                                      |
| 12d2257c-c02b-4295-b910-2069f583bee5 | 20.0.0.92        | 99.99.99.92        | 37ebfa4c-c0f9-459a-a63b-fb2e84ab7f92 |
| 98c5a929-e125-411d-8a18-89877d3c932b |                  | 99.99.99.93        |                                      |
| f55e54fb-e50a-4800-9a6e-1d75004a2541 | 20.0.0.94        | 99.99.99.94        | fe996e76-ffdb-4687-91a0-9b4df2631b4e |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Now I want to fetch all the *"floating _ip_address"* for which *"port_id"* & *"fixed_ip_address"* fields are **blank/empty** (In above sample 99.99.99.91 & 99.99.99.93)

How can I do it with shell scripting?

Comment: What all have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
fl_ips=($(sed -nE 's/\|.*\|.*\|(.*)\|\s*\|/\1/p' inputfile))
```

Here `inputfile` is the table provided in the question. The array `fl_ips` contains the output of `sed`:

```
>echo ${#fl_ips[@]}
2                    # Array has two elements
>echo ${fl_ips[0]}
99.99.99.91
>echo ${fl_ips[1]}                                                         
99.99.99.93
```